# Increment quantity by one (+1) if the product id is exist in current datagridview

Tags: c#, oracle, datagridview

Increment quantity by one (+1) if the product id is exist in current datagridview

My datagridview has 9 columns:

```
Column 1 = Edit_Checkbox            Column 2 = ItemCount

Column 3 = DGV_PRODUCT_ID           Column 4 = DGV_PRODUCT_DESC

Column 5 = DGV_UNIT_PRICE           Column 6 = DGV_QUANTITY

Column 7 = DGV_DISCOUNT             Column 8 = DGV_TOTAL_PRICE

Column 9 = DGV_NOTES
```

I am trying to increment quantity by one (+1) if the product id exists in current datagridview

My code below works fine but I have an issue which is when same product id exists it will 
increment the Quantity by one if the process is done sequentially, But if I entered a product id
 in a non-sequential way it will not increment quantity by one, instead inserting a new row in datagridview.

**For example:**

Enter product id number 1003 2 item quantity will be 2

Enter product id number 3000 1 item quantity will be 1

Enter product id number 1003 1 item quantity will still be 1 when the product already exists in datagridview. How do I avoid that case ?

```
private void SelectedProductData()
        {
            int ItemCount = DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Count;
            bool ProductIDExist = false;

            string connstr = @"Data Source=orcl; User Id=user; password=pwd;";
            string cmdtxt = @"SELECT PRODUCT_ID,
                                     PRODUCT_DESC,
                                     UNIT_PRICE
                              FROM WAREHOUSE
                                WHERE PRODUCT_ID = :P_Product_ID";

            try
            {
                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = cmdtxt;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_Product_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = TB_Product_ID.Text;

                    OracleDataReader oraReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (oraReader.Read())
                    {
                        ItemCount++;
                        RowCountLabel.Text = ItemCount.ToString();

                        DataGridViewRow dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow();

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow ItemRow in DGV_INVOICE.Rows)
                        {
                          if (Convert.ToString(ItemRow.Cells[2].Value) == TB_Product_ID.Text)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ItemRow.Cells[2].Value) + "  1  " + TB_Product_ID.Text);
                                ProductIDExist = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (ProductIDExist)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("2");
                            //dgvRow.Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt64(dgvRow.Cells[5].Value));
                            DGV_INVOICE.Rows[dgvRow.Index].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt64(dgvRow.Cells[5].Value));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("3");

                            //Add the row to grid view for the first time
                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell());   //Edit_Checkbox     index 0
                            dgvRow.Cells[0].Value = false;

                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());    //ItemCount         index 1
                            dgvRow.Cells[1].Value = ItemCount;

                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());    //DGV_PRODUCT_ID    index 2
                            dgvRow.Cells[2].Value = oraReader.GetValue(0);

                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());    //DGV_PRODUCT_DESC  index 3
                            dgvRow.Cells[3].Value = oraReader.GetString(1);

                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());    //DGV_UNIT_PRICE    index 4
                            dgvRow.Cells[4].Value = oraReader.GetValue(2);

                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());    //DGV_QUANTITY      index 5
                            dgvRow.Cells[5].Value = "1";

                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());    //DGV_DISCOUNT      index 6
                            dgvRow.Cells[6].Value = "0";

                            //dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());  //DGV_TOTAL_PRICE   index 7
                            //dgvRow.Cells[7].Value = "0";

                            //dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());  //DGV_NOTES         index 8
                            //dgvRow.Cells[8].Value = "-";

                            DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Add(dgvRow);
                            dgvRow.Selected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception EX)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(EX.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                TB_ORDER_NOTE.Text = EX.Message;            /* Testing Purpose */
            }
        }
```

Comment: You say your grid has 4 columns but you reference a 6th column with the line `DGV_INVOICE.Rows[ItemRow.Index].Cells[5].Value=...` as if its the 6th, not the 3rd, column that contains the quantity. Why is this? Also (assuming 4 columns) in the `if` statement, wouldn't `ItemRow.Cells[2]` be referencing the quantity, not the price? Why not check by id rather than price?

Comment: @theKunz its just an example to explain my case

Comment: Can we see the actual code you are using?

Comment: @theKunz yes I had update my post with full code now

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try

```
bool ProductIDExist = false;
foreach (DataGridViewRow ItemRow in DGV_INVOICE.Rows)
{
    //Check if the product Id exists with the same Price
    ProductIDExist |= Convert.ToString(ItemRow.Cells[1].Value) == TB_Product_ID.Text

    if (productIDExist)
    {
        break;
    }
}

if (productIDExist)
{
    //increase quantity by 1
}
else
{
    //add a new row
}
```

Comment: Error message `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index`
on  `messagebox.show("4"); ` I will post code modified according to your suggestion